# C++ Union usage

Tags: c++, unions

So far I have just used unions to store either member A or member B. 
I do now find myself in the case where I want to **change the used member during runtime**.

```
union NextGen {
    std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord> Child = nullptr;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord>> Children;
};
```

My current usage:

```
void TreeRecord::AddChild(const std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord>& NewChild) {
    if(_childCount == 0) {
        _nextGeneration.Child = NewChild;
        _childCount++;
    } else if(_childCount == 1) {
        //This is not clear to me:
        //Do I have to set Child to nullptr first?
        //Do I need to clear the Children vecor?
        //Or will it work like this?
        _nextGeneration.Children.push_back(_nextGeneration.Child);
        _nextGeneration.Children.push_back(NewChild);
        _childCount++;
    } else {
        _nextGeneration.Children.push_back(NewChild);
        _childCount++;
    }
}
```

---

**New implementation (try):**

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord> singlechild_type;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord>> children_type;



union {
    singlechild_type _child;
    children_type _children;
};



void TreeRecord::AddChild(const singlechild_type& NewChild) {
    if(_childCount == 0) {
        _child = NewChild;
        _childCount = 1;

    } else if(_childCount == 1) {
        singlechild_type currentChild = _child; //Copy pointer
        _child.~singlechild_type(); //Destruct old union member
        new (&_children) children_type(); //Construct new union member
        _children.push_back(currentChild); //Add old child to vector
        _children.push_back(NewChild); //Add new child to vector
        _childCount = 2;

    } else {
        _children.push_back(NewChild);
        _childCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) compliant compiler. Read about [union](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)-s.

In general, you need to *explicitly* call the destructor of the old union member, and then the constructor of the new union member. Actually, you'll better have [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), with the actual `union` being anonymous and member of some class:

```
class TreeRecord;

class TreeRecord {
   bool hassinglechild;
   typedef std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord> singlechild_type;
   typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TreeRecord>> children_type;
   union {
     singlechild_type child;  // when hassinglechild is true
     children_type children;  // when hassinglechild is false
   }
   TreeRecord() : hassinglechild(true), child(nullptr) {};
   void set_child(TreeRecord&ch) {
     if (!hassinglechild) {
       children.~children_type();
       hassinglechild = true;
       new (&child) singlechild_type(nullptr);
     };
     child = ch;
   }
   /// other constructors and destructors skipped
   /// more code needed, per rule of five
}
```

Notice that I am explicitly calling the destructor `~children_type()` then I am using the placement `new`  to *explicitly* call the constructor for `child`.

Don't forget to follow the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). So you need more code above

See also [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html)

BTW your code is suggesting that you distinguish the case when you have a `child` and the case when you have a one-element vector of `children`. Is that voluntary and meaningful?

PS. In some languages, notably Ocaml, tagged unions (a.k.a. sum types) are considerably easier to define and implement than in C++11.... See wikipage of [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Comment: Didn't even thought about that! What do you mean by "in general"

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it would be nice if you elaborate.

Comment: I won't have a one elem vector. I either use Child for 0 or 1 elem and I switch to vector for more elems than 1. Or did I made a mistake...? (I am still reading your code) And I am using a tagged union, just not with a boolean identifier but with "size_t _childCount", which is 0 or 1 when Child is beeing used.

Comment: But the `std::vector` carries its own `_childCount` as its `size()`, so you just want a boolean flag

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrblit: I just mentioned it, but what might be wrong with boost is the additional dependency it requires. Sometimes people dislike that (and I understand that opinion).

Comment: @NoëlWidmer: it probably should work. Use your debugger to test it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Will do, thanks. i was just interested if I understood the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note, using more than one element of a `union` concurrently invokes undefined behavior, e.g.

```
    _nextGeneration.Children.push_back(_nextGeneration.Child);
```

As @BasileStarynkevitch mentioned, one way is to avoid this is a tagged union.